# merge dataframes based on date range in R

Tags: r, date, merge

I have two dataframes that I need to merge based on an ID and date ranges.
df1 has columns SiteID, and date and df2 has columns SiteID, Start Date, and End Date. I'm looking to end up with a df that includes SiteID, Date, Start Date and End Date.

example df1:

```
            DateTime SiteID
1 2010-07-25 01:06:55    B04
2 2011-05-10 23:52:14    B04
3 2011-09-17 01:14:30    B04
4 2012-04-04 02:55:29    B05
5 2013-01-05 23:03:06    B05
6 2011-03-09 20:39:46    B06
7 2012-07-25 23:17:19    B07
8 2011-03-03 00:46:45    B08
```

example df2:

```
  Site.ID Start.date   End.date
1      B04 2010-07-18 2010-08-24
2      B04 2011-02-22 2011-07-23
3      B04 2011-08-30 2012-10-03
4      B04 2012-10-20 2013-04-08
5      B05 2011-08-30 2012-08-21
6      B05 2012-12-08 2013-01-21
7      B05 2013-02-08 2013-04-08
8      B06 2010-07-20 2010-09-03
9      B06 2011-02-12 2011-04-18
10     B06 2011-05-13 2011-05-16
11     B07 2011-10-24 2011-11-29
12     B07 2011-12-29 2012-12-02
13     B08 2011-02-12 2011-04-01
14     B08 2011-10-24 2011-12-24
```

what I'm looking to create:

```
        DateTime SiteID Start.date   End.date
1 2010-07-25 01:06:55    B04 2010-07-18 2010-08-24
2 2011-05-10 23:52:14    B04 2011-02-22 2011-07-23
3 2011-09-17 01:14:30    B04 2011-08-30 2012-10-03
4 2012-04-04 02:55:29    B05 2011-08-30 2012-08-21
5 2013-01-05 23:03:06    B05 2012-12-08 2013-01-21
6 2011-03-09 20:39:46    B06 2011-02-12 2011-04-18
7 2012-07-25 23:17:19    B07 2011-12-29 2012-12-02
8 2011-03-03 00:46:45    B08 2011-02-12 2011-04-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you are using `lubridate` for the `DateTime`, you can do

```r
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c("SiteID" = "Site.ID")) %>% 
  filter(DateTime %within% interval(Start.date, End.date))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   DateTime            SiteID Start.date End.date  
#>   <dttm>              <chr>  <date>     <date>    
#> 1 2010-07-25 01:06:55 B04    2010-07-18 2010-08-24
#> 2 2011-05-10 23:52:14 B04    2011-02-22 2011-07-23
#> 3 2011-09-17 01:14:30 B04    2011-08-30 2012-10-03
#> 4 2012-04-04 02:55:29 B05    2011-08-30 2012-08-21
#> 5 2013-01-05 23:03:06 B05    2012-12-08 2013-01-21
#> 6 2011-03-09 20:39:46 B06    2011-02-12 2011-04-18
#> 7 2012-07-25 23:17:19 B07    2011-12-29 2012-12-02
#> 8 2011-03-03 00:46:45 B08    2011-02-12 2011-04-01
```

---

Full Example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union


df1 <- tribble(~DateTime, ~SiteID,
"2010-07-25 01:06:55", "B04",
"2011-05-10 23:52:14", "B04",
"2011-09-17 01:14:30", "B04",
"2012-04-04 02:55:29", "B05",
"2013-01-05 23:03:06", "B05",
"2011-03-09 20:39:46", "B06",
"2012-07-25 23:17:19", "B07",
"2011-03-03 00:46:45", "B08") %>% 
  mutate(DateTime = as_datetime(DateTime))


df2 <- tribble(~Site.ID, ~Start.date, ~End.date,
"B04", "2010-07-18", "2010-08-24",
"B04", "2011-02-22", "2011-07-23",
"B04", "2011-08-30", "2012-10-03",
"B04", "2012-10-20", "2013-04-08",
"B05", "2011-08-30", "2012-08-21",
"B05", "2012-12-08", "2013-01-21",
"B05", "2013-02-08", "2013-04-08",
"B06", "2010-07-20", "2010-09-03",
"B06", "2011-02-12", "2011-04-18",
"B06", "2011-05-13", "2011-05-16",
"B07", "2011-10-24", "2011-11-29",
"B07", "2011-12-29", "2012-12-02",
"B08", "2011-02-12", "2011-04-01",
"B08", "2011-10-24", "2011-12-24") %>% 
  mutate(Start.date = as_date(Start.date), End.date = as_date(End.date))


df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c("SiteID" = "Site.ID")) %>% 
  filter(DateTime %within% interval(Start.date, End.date))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   DateTime            SiteID Start.date End.date  
#>   <dttm>              <chr>  <date>     <date>    
#> 1 2010-07-25 01:06:55 B04    2010-07-18 2010-08-24
#> 2 2011-05-10 23:52:14 B04    2011-02-22 2011-07-23
#> 3 2011-09-17 01:14:30 B04    2011-08-30 2012-10-03
#> 4 2012-04-04 02:55:29 B05    2011-08-30 2012-08-21
#> 5 2013-01-05 23:03:06 B05    2012-12-08 2013-01-21
#> 6 2011-03-09 20:39:46 B06    2011-02-12 2011-04-18
#> 7 2012-07-25 23:17:19 B07    2011-12-29 2012-12-02
#> 8 2011-03-03 00:46:45 B08    2011-02-12 2011-04-01
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - this works on my example dataset. I just tried this on the real much larger dataset and the left join ends up dropping around 4000 rows of data (i'm assuming there are date typos that are being filtered out. Is there a way to keep all records and just return NAs in the case of mismatched data?

Comment: `left_join` keeps all values in `x` (ie. the left-hand side); if you also want to keep all values on the right-hand side, you could use `full_join` instead.
If this does not help, feel free to ask again.

Comment: I am still losing the rows with full_join. Do you know of a way to extract the rows that were dropped in the join/filter?

Comment: I found the missing rows, and it appears to be that if the DateTime from df1 occurred on the end date, the row was excluded. Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: Found my own workaround! used as.Date to create a DateOnly column from DateTime in df1, and this fixed the issue.